# Validation of collection item against entire collection to prevent duplicates

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I 'm working on a project in C#/WPF using MVVM. 
A simplified scenario that expresses my problem is as follows:

There is a `Person` class, which has a `Name` property of type `string`.
Then a `House` class holds an `ObservableCollection` of `Person` objects (called `People`).
The `Person` instances in the `House` are not allowed to have the same `Name`, so there is a check whenever a `Person` is added to the collection.

In WPF, I have a `ListBox` with an `ItemTemplate` containing a `TextBox` that is bound to the `Name` of each `Person` (TwoWay), so the user can change it.

The problem there is, how to perform validation against the entire collection, to check if another person already has the name the user entered?

**UPDATED:**

So I am trying to use a custom `ValidationRule` for this, where I need to pass the collection as arguments. In fact, I need to pass the ViewModel which holds the collection (the `DataContext` of `ListBox`) and the `Person` for which the validation occurs.

So, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058748/how-to-pass-list-view-as-parameter-to-the-validation-rule-of-a-cell-template/8058782#8058782) post, I have a `MyValidationRule` object derived from `ValidationRule` which has a property of type `PersonValidationContext`. The `PersonValidationContext` class is derived from `FrameworkElement` and has two `DependencyProperty` properties, one for the ViewModel and the other for the current Person.

As answered by [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) in the post mentioned, a workaround to binding to the `ListBox` would be by using `x:Reference`, as the validation rules are not part of the visual tree. So after all I have

```
<ListBox Name="personsList"
     ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
     Margin="0,0"
     BorderThickness="0"
     SelectionMode="Single">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBlock Text="Name: " Grid.Column="0" />
              <TextBox x:Name="nameTextBox" Grid.Column="1">
                 <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True"               
                        ValidatesOnExceptions="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"         
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                       <Binding.ValidationRules>
                          <valid:MyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                             <valid:MyValidationRule.ValidationContext>                                                                            
                                <valid:PersonValidationContext ViewModel="{Binding 
                                         Source={x:Reference Name=personsList}, 
                                          Path=DataContext}"                                                                                                   
                                        Person="{Binding Source={x:Reference
                                             Name=personsList}, Path=Items/}"/>
                             </valid:MyValidationRule.ValidationContext>
                          </valid:MyValidationRule>
                       </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                 </TextBox.Text>
              </TextBox>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So this works as far as passing the ViewModel. However, the `Person` binding always points to the first item in the collection (i.e. the first `Person`). Does anyone know anything about this? Any suggestions on how to bind to the selected item?

Also, I am trying to force validation on all persons' `Name`s whenever one is updated, in order to ensure correct behavior (consider if the user changes Person1's name to the same name as Person2, the validation error appears, then the user changes Person2's name to something different, the error does not disappear as it should).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your requirement is that the `Person` class must not accept a new `Name` value if any other member of the `People` collection has the same name.  There's no way to meet the requirement unless either `Person` or the validating code has access to that collection of people, either directly or indirectly.  The custom `ValidationRule` seems like the way to go.  Can you give more details of what you tried and why it didn't work?  Sample code?  Exceptions or incorrect behavior?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Please see question for updated sample code.

Answer (score 0):

An object by design is not aware that is is a member of a collection.  If you want a reference to the collection you need to pass it.  But you can have one constructor that passes the parent collection and the other that does not.  If the parent collection is null then simply don't check for duplicates.